# Using PUTTY to SSH to Linux - neither .bashrc nor .rlogin execute

Tags: ssh, putty

What does ssh use as startup script?
My understanding is that it should invoke ~/.bashrc, in my case it does not, so what could prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things.  The most likely place to look is the server side SSH config (sshd_config).  Another place to look is to see what shell is associated with the user.  Obviously if it's not a bash shell then .bashrc won't get used at all.